# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: adding variable to all templates' context

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How can I add a "global" variable such as username to be used all around my template context?

Currently I am setting these explicitly to each ModelAndView object in my TemplateController.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Several ways to do this.

If you want to add a variable to all views served by a single controller, you can add a `@ModelAttribute` annotated method - [see reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods).

Note that you can also, using the same `@ModelAttribute`
 mechanism, address multiple Controllers at once. For that, you can implement that `@ModelAttribute` method in a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` - [see reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice).

Answer (score 12):

`@ControllerAdvice` work for me:

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class AnnotationAdvice {

     @Autowired
     UserServiceImpl userService;

     @ModelAttribute("currentUser")
     public User getCurrentUser() {
         UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) 
         SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
               .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

      return userService.findUserByEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

If you simply want something from your `application.properties` into your `thymeleaf` template, then you can make use of Spring's [**SpEL**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

```
${@environment.getProperty('name.of.the.property')}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may like to have look at @ModelAttribute. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

> Blockquote
>   In Thymeleaf, these model attributes (or context variables in Thymeleaf jargon) can be accessed with the following syntax: ${attributeName}, where attributeName in our case is messages. This is a Spring EL expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for Spring Boot and Thymeleaf.

First, we need to create a `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MvcAdvice {

    // adds a global value to every model
    @ModelAttribute("baseUrl")
    public String test() {
        return HttpUtil.getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

Now, we have access to `baseUrl` in our templates:

```
<span th:text=${baseUrl}></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to give a code sample as per accepted answer from Brian Clozel:

[ControllerAdvice](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/java/com/contentplusplus/springboot/controller/GetPrincipalController.java):

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Controller.class)
public class GetPrincipalController {

    @ModelAttribute("principal")
    public Object getCurrentUser() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
}
```

After above, you will get an object of principal and then you can use everything from that object "GLOBALLY" in your application, in any of your Thyemleaf Template [like this](https://github.com/ajkr195/ContentPlusPlus/blob/main/src/main/resources/templates/fragments/navbar.html):

```
<li><span th:text="${principal.getUsername()}"></span></li>
<li><span th:text="${principal.getAuthorities()}"></span></li>
```